# Почему несколько js-файлов склеены?

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте js-скрипты подключаются примерно так:

```
<script src="js/init.js+programming.js.pagespeed.jc.0CvsngqB5t.js"></script>
```

но в папке js эти все скрипты лежат отдельно, и если их редактировать и залить по фтп, то изменений на сайте не видно.
т.е. в папке js лежат такие файлы: init.js,  programming.js
Подскажите, как эти скрипты компилируются в один файл и как вносить в них изменения?
`pagespeed.jc.0CvsngqB5t.js` такого файла в папке js нет. Откуда он?

Comment: все зависит от фреймворка или системы которую вы используете, нужно читать документацию. Все файлы преобразуются в один, чтобы уменьшить запросы на сервер. Изменений нет, так как скорее всего этот файл храниться где-то в кеше и в зависимости  от фреймворка или системы надо его как-то переписать

Comment: @Jurij Jazdanov, по фтп нигде на нашёл кэш, в котором бы были эти файлы, что посоветуете?

Answer (score 4):

Файлы склеены для того, чтобы вместо нескольких http-соединений использовать одно. Это одна из техник оптимизации веб-сайтов, позволяющая избежать оверхэда на установку соединения и передачу http-заголовков, а также более рационально использовать одновременные 8 соединений с одним доменом, которые может позволить браузер.

По-хорошему, где-то в имени файла должен быть хэш, чтобы можно было нормально использовать кэширование (сделать его постоянным), но в вопросе его не заметно.

Попробуй обновить страницу без использования кэша - при помощи Ctrl+F5, либо открыв в приватном окне. Если поможет, то сервер стоит как-то перенастроить, чтобы в имени файла был хэш. Если не поможет, то никаких данных, чтобы тебе чем-то помочь с настройкой в вопросе вообще нет.

Comment: нашёл в чём причина. Вобщем сайт находится на хостинге http://www.ukraine.com.ua/ и в админке сайта выбрано "Объединять все скрипты JavaScript в один файл", и после очистки кэша изменения видно  http://clip2net.com/s/3NwENHY

Comment: @word, серверного или клиентского? И раз уж ответ помог, прими его нажатием на галочку слева.

Comment: я сам нашёл решение, но благодарю за подсказку

Comment: @word, в таком случае его стоит оформить в виде ответа. только по-подробнее желательно.